# preventDefault not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="text" class="additionalName">
        <span class="additionalNameError"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.additionalName').on("keypress",function (f) {
                                if (!alphaOnly(f)) {
                                    $(".additionalNameError").show().html("&nbsp;You must use text only - see <a href='#name_rules'>name rules</a>").fadeOut("slow").delay(10000);
                                    f.preventDefault();
                                    return false; 
                                    //event.preventDefault();
                                    //return false;
                                }
                            });

                            function alphaOnly(e) {
                                var inp = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
                                if (/[a-zA-Z-']/.test(inp)) return true;
                                else return false;
                            };
    });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The code works well in Chrome but not in Firefox. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. I have tried adding the `event` variable in the `preventDefault` method but nothing seems to work

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly isn't working in FX?

Comment: The `alphaOnly` method returns when a user types a number in the input field. In Firefox, I can't type either letters or numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per jQuery docs it is recommended to use `event.which` for key events.

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.

Reference: [event.which docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: This works well on all browsers and devices but not on a Sony Z1 phone.

Comment: @NoahNathan not sure what to tell you other than might have to create a test for feature support or look for other issues online related to that device

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, firefox always returns the key pressed as 0 when you use `keypress` (meaning that your function will always trigger). If you change this to trigger on `keyup`instead, it works fine.